# Вопрос про классы c++

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-studio, классы

Всем привет. При написании класса вектора появились вопросы:
1.Как сделать так чтобы классу можно было присваивать значения даже после инициализации, пример:

```
Vector2 vect2(120, 5);
vect2(120, 5); или vect2 = 120,5
```

2.Как сделать так чтобы можно было использовать класс за 2-3 переменные сразу пример:

```
obj.Position(120, 5); // как должно выглядеть

Vector2(120, 5);
obj.Position(Vector2);// про, что я говорил
```

Код класса: (Vector2.h)

```
#pragma once

class Vector2
{
public:
    Vector2(int x, int y);
    int GetVector2();
    int X;
    int Y;
};
```

Vector2.cpp

```
#include "Vector2.h"

Vector2::Vector2(int x, int y)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}

int Vector2::GetVector2()
{
    return X, Y;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Например, `vect2 = Vector2(120,5);` — если, конечно, конструктор и оператор присвоения написаны корректно. В вашем случае используется оператор, сгенерированный компилятором, но для данной операции его достаточно.
2. Написать свою функцию, принимающую вектор. Или передавать значения из вектора как отдельные аргументы (типа, `Vector2 v(120, 5); obj.Position(v.X, v.Y);`)

Замечу вскользь, что код

```
int Vector2::GetVector2()
{
    return X, Y;
}
```

возвращает только одно значение — `Y` (см. "оператор "запятая"").

Comment: Спасибо, я всё понял.